# How to add Numbers to String with DOM

Tags: javascript, string, dom, numbers

I have one task. So if HTML result give me

```
"Великолепный век 1 сезон 1-24 серия смотреть онлайн"

"Сериал Шелест 2 сезон 1-2, 3, 4 серия смотреть онлайн бесплатно в хорошем качестве hd 720"
```

it should be like this

```
"Великолепный век 1 сезон 1-24, 25, 26, 27... серия смотреть онлайн"

"Сериал Шелест 2 сезон 1-2, 3, 4" + "5, 6, 7, 8, 9" + "серия смотреть онлайн бесплатно в хорошем качестве hd 720"
```

so i need to add number to string with js, and it should work for every site ?
i hope that somebody gotta help me!

Comment: What determines how many numbers you add? What is the code that you've tried?

Comment: i've tried with for loop, but i don't know how to get length of numbers from string ( numbers should < 32

Comment: can you post the html?

Comment: @RajSharma sure `<title>Сериал Шелест 2 сезон 1-2, 3, 4 серия смотреть онлайн бесплатно в хорошем качестве hd 720</title> `

Comment: how to write html code know?please show me javascript code.

What is the basis of what numbers?

Comment: @hamedhossani so it's a problem i don't know how to get numbers length from string in html. and i don't know how to add numbers into html. 

 `for (var i = 'last number?'; i < 32; i++)  `

Comment: your description is insufficient to understand me.
please describe! Whats is the original Text? where are the Numbers that are added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var list = document.getElementById("title").innerHTML;

var start = list.indexOf("сезон");
var end = list.indexOf("серия");

var numbers = 32;
var newhtml = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= numbers; i++) {
  if (i == 1) newhtml = newhtml + i + "-";
  else newhtml = newhtml + i + ", "
}

newhtml = list.substr(0, start) + "сезон " + newhtml.substr(0, newhtml.length - 2) + " " + list.substr(end, list.length);
document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = newhtml;

console.log(newhtml);
```

```html
<title id="title">Сериал Шелест 2 сезон 1-2, 3, 4 серия смотреть онлайн бесплатно в хорошем качестве hd 720</title>
```